# Overnight bi-weekly recurring events using rrule in fullcalendar angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, rrule, fullcalendar-5

Looking to create an overnight event that repeats every 2 weeks in fullcalendar using rrule plugin in angular 10

- Event starts Monday 8PM ends Wednesday 11AM that repeats every other week.
- I used the following for the rrule:

```
rrule: {
  freq: RRule.WEEKLY,
  interval: 2,
},
```

I have not been able to create the overnight event using fullcalendar and rrule plugin.

I was able to create a simple recurring one day event that repeats every other week.

Currently using

1. angular 10.1.0
2. fullcalendar/angular 5.3.1
3. fullcalendar/rrule 5.3.1

Thanks for your feedback and input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event object would need to look like this:

```
{
  title: 'my recurring event',
  duration: '39:00',
  rrule: {
    freq: 'weekly',
    interval: 2,
    byweekday: [ 'mo'],
    dtstart: '2020-09-01T20:00:00'
  }
}
```

Let's break that down according to the different requirements:

- starts Monday 8PM: this is fulfilled by the time in the `dtstart`. (Of course you can specify any start *date* you wish.)
- ends Wednesday 11AM - an event which start at 8pm on Monday and ends 11am on Wednesday is 39 hours long. Therefore we can set the `duration` of the event itself (not in the rrule) to make this work
- repeats every other week - this is fulfilled by the `freq` and `interval` settings which you had already figured out.

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abNMoZK